# how can I obtain the value of subject of the Stanford Dependencies "nsubj" of a tree?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

This is a part of my code:

```
String sentence="My dog also likes eating sausage.";
LexicalizedParser lp = new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser.gz"); 
TokenizerFactory tf = PTBTokenizer.factory(false, new WordTokenFactory());
TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");

List tokens = tf.getTokenizer(new StringReader(sentence)).tokenize(); 
lp.parse(tokens); // parse the tokens
Tree t = lp.getBestParse();
```

How can I get the value of the subject (dog)?

This is a dependency where I would like to extract the Subject:

```
nsubj(likes-4, dog-2)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
String sentence="My dog also likes eating sausage.";
LexicalizedParser lp = new LexicalizedParser("resources/stanford-parser-2011-06-27/grammar/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
TokenizerFactory tf = PTBTokenizer.factory(false, new WordTokenFactory());
TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");

List tokens = tf.getTokenizer(new StringReader(sentence)).tokenize();
lp.parse(tokens); // parse the tokens
Tree t = lp.getBestParse();

TreebankLanguagePack languagePack = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
GrammaticalStructure structure = languagePack.grammaticalStructureFactory().newGrammaticalStructure(t);
Collection<TypedDependency> typedDependencies = structure.typedDependenciesCollapsed();

for(TypedDependency td : typedDependencies) {
  if(td.reln().equals(EnglishGrammaticalRelations.NOMINAL_SUBJECT)) {
    System.out.println(td);
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
nsubj(likes-4, dog-2)
```